# Windows 10 loop installation

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to install Windows 10 on my laptop into which I just put an SSD. I downloaded the ISO from the official Microsft page and I proceeded to do the installation from a USB drive, but the installation loops and does not let you install.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BF-tIUdRP6o
I leave you that video of reference to the problem that happens to me.
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 stuck in install loop](https://superuser.com/questions/1373897/windows-10-stuck-in-install-loop)

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate what you used to create the installation USB media.

Comment: According to your video, it is not even trying to boot (or else being entirely unsuccessful). Try booting with a different USB Key.  Also, if this is not the HP created recovery key, you may need to turn OFF Secure Boot in BIOS

Answer (score 1):

Boot from the USB Drive once again. Continue until you see this screen:
[image: Upgrade & Custom options]

Select custom. Delete everything but unallocated space for Drive 0. Once you have Drive 0 unallocated, select that space and hit next. The installation should continue normally.

Hope this helps.